# Unable to see shared folders of another Ubuntu computer. Other computers are fine

Tags: 22.04, samba, file-sharing

I have a Ubuntu 22.04 media server setup with shared folders. I have set up Samba with the users and passwords.  I can see the Ubuntu media server and access all the shared folders from Windows and my iPhone.

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04 on another machine.  Samba is also installed.  I can see the Ubuntu media server in "other locations" but not any of the shared folders.  When I click on the Media Server only folder that shows up is a "print$" folder.

I'm not sure if it matters, but the username: password are the same on the Ubuntu media server as well as the new Ubuntu computer I'm trying to access from. Is there some sort of conflict?

Any idea what the problem is?